# emojioneArea not converted images tag

Tags: html, emoji, emojione

This is my HTML code:

```
<textarea name="edit_comment" class="edit-comment">
    // This is the comment content that will be edited (getting from database)
    Hello John <img alt="" class="emojioneemoji" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.2.7/assets/png/1f603.png">
</textarea>
```

When I try to edit the comment this is the output that giving to me:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTYm3.png

How can make emojioneArea remove the image tag and just add the emoji?

Comment: refer to this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/ukLaz8cm/6/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use unicode for emoji instead of image tag.
 `p &#x1F601`